# VueJS: How do I use data from main.js in my templates?

Tags: javascript, components, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have my Vue scope in my main.js:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App },
  data: {
    name: 'Levi'
  }
})
```

and I want to use it in my template: `test.vue`:

`<p>My name is {{ name }}`

I'm using vue-router for all the routing functionality, and that all works fine. But when I try calling `name` in my template I get

`[Vue warn]: Property or method "name" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of your issue, you can start [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mimani/gLay3u52/).

Comment: @mplungjan I did actually already look through all the page 1 posts for the error before posting, but I decided to go back and I guess I glanced over something near the bottom. Just had to replace `export default` with `module.exports`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had to add a script tag in my template and use `module.exports` not `export default`

Comment: Please feel free to delete the question unless you find that it is useful for future visitors